# Will I be able to run my site on PHP 7.0?

Tags: 7

I've started reading about some performance benchmarks with PHP 7.0 which suggest that it is spectacularly much faster. I've searched all over for information on Drupal support for PHP 7.0, but all that I can find concerns Drupal 8 whereas I am still working for the moment on Drupal 7.

I have found [this article that concerns Drupal on Windows](http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/benchmarking-drupal-7-php-7-dev), which suggests that D7 on PHP7 works, however since I am running on Centos or Ubuntu I would welcome any information anyone might have on this.

My concern is particularly strong because I am just getting started on a project with massive data inputs, which will thus be very performance sensitive.

Comment: PHP 7 is still in RC isn't it? I don't think it's a good idea to put all your eggs in that one basket until there's at least a stable release. What if the answer now is "yes", but "no" when that release happens?

Comment: Voted to close as too broad, because there was 28 bugfixes beetween RC1 and RC2, and more are expected to come. Without knowing if and how they will be resolved, we can't answer. Also, whilst I believe core will work (my faith, not any actual data), nobody can tell about your choice of modules. First, because you didn't provide it, second, because it would be way too long for Q&A format.

Comment: Now that there is PHP 7 support in D7 core and PHP 7 has officially been released, I think this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical [Drupal 8 issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2454439) is tagged "Needs backport to D7", which indicates the community intends to support Drupal 7 on PHP 7 but it may take a little time.

Comment: Not quite. It only indicates community want it to happen. It does not indicate that anyone declared to put his effort for it to happen...

Comment: Drupal 8 core committers have commented on that issue and have discussed the Drupal 7 situation and a co-maintainer of Drupal 7 marked it for backport to Drupal 7. I disagree with your comment entirely and I don't know what other vote of support you are looking for.

Comment: Note that there is a separate issue for Drupal 7, which is close to wrapping up now that Drupal 7.50 has been released: [Fully support PHP 7 in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/2656548)